# can't deserialize with boost::serialization and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr, boost-serialization

I implemented the class structure below. I would like to serialize these objects.

```
class Base
{
public:
  Base(void) = default;

  virtual double func(void) const = 0;


private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {}
}; 

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
  DerivedA(void) = default;
  DerivedA(double a)
  : a_(a) {}

  virtual double func(void) const
  {
    return std::exp(a_);
  }

private:
  double a_; 

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & a_;
  }
}; 


class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
  DerivedB(void) = default;
  DerivedB(double b)
  : b_(b) {}

  virtual double func(void) const
  {
    return std::log(b_);
  }

 private:
   double b_; 

   friend class boost::serialization::access;
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
   {
     ar & b_;
   }
 };
```

I want to create a vector of shared_ptr to these objects and serialize and deserialize them. Serialization seems ok, but I can't get them deserialized. Any ideas?

```
void out(void)
{
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> objects;
  std::shared_ptr<Base> m1(new DerivedA(1.0));
  std::shared_ptr<Base> m2(new DerivedB(4.0));
  objects.push_back(m1);
  objects.push_back(m2);

  std::ofstream ofs("filename");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);

  for(auto o : objects)
  {
    oa << *o;
  }
}

void in(void)
{
  std::ifstream ifs(filename);
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> objects;

  std::shared_ptr<Base> m1(new DerivedA());
  ia >> *m1;
  models.push_back(m1);
  std::shared_ptr<Base> m2(new DerivedB());
  ia >> *m2;
  models.push_back(m2);  
}
```

Cheers, Mike

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo but I don’t see where the variable “filename” is declared in your “in” function. Unless filename=”filename” your ifstream is likely reading the wrong file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e442fc3fc2cd4111)**

Note:

- the use of `boost::shared_ptr`
- the use of

  ```
  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(DerivedA)
  BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(DerivedB)
  ```
- the use of

  ```
  ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
  ```

  to establish the polymorphic link
- the use of

  ```
  ar.template register_type<DerivedA>();
  ar.template register_type<DerivedB>();
  ```
- the serialization through a pointer, not a (l)value

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <fstream>

class DerivedA;
class DerivedB;

class Base
{
    public:
        Base(void) = default;
        virtual ~Base() = default;

        virtual double func(void) const = 0;

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                ar.template register_type<DerivedA>();
                ar.template register_type<DerivedB>();
            }
}; 

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;

class DerivedA : public Base
{
    public:
        DerivedA(void) = default;
        DerivedA(double a)
            : a_(a) {}

        virtual double func(void) const
        {
            return std::exp(a_);
        }

    private:
        double a_; 

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
                ar & a_;
            }
}; 


class DerivedB : public Base
{
    public:
        DerivedB(void) = default;
        DerivedB(double b)
            : b_(b) {}

        virtual double func(void) const
        {
            return std::log(b_);
        }

    private:
        double b_; 

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
                ar & b_;
            }
}; 

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(DerivedA)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(DerivedB)

void out(std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<BasePtr> objects;
    BasePtr m1(new DerivedA(1.0));
    BasePtr m2(new DerivedB(4.0));
    objects.push_back(m1);
    objects.push_back(m2);

    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa.template register_type<DerivedA>();
    oa.template register_type<DerivedB>();

    oa << objects;
}

std::vector<BasePtr > in(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia.template register_type<DerivedA>();
    ia.template register_type<DerivedB>();

    std::vector<BasePtr> objects;

    ia >> objects;

    return objects;
}

int main()
{
    out("test.out");
    auto r = in("test.out");
    return r.size();
}
```

Comment: as a follow-up? what is the problem with std::shared_ptr?

Comment: @Mike yeah, well, it's not supported :) It should be pretty easy to adapt it (just copy/paste from `serialization/shared_ptr.hpp` I guess).

Comment: cheers. I'll look into it at some stage.